# how to: when marker is clicked - dim the map and show a big div instead of an infobox on top of the map with information

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, jquery-ui-map

I have a **Google Map** with filterable markers and `info-boxes` containing simple information about each marker( *when you click them* ), but was wondering if this is possible:

When you would `click` on a marker - instead of a default `info-box` a big `div` appears on top of the map with tabs which shows all the possible data I will provide about a marker via **JSON** ( images, links, pictures ).

How would you approach about implementing this functionality?

[image]

Comment: [www.whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: You are right. I'm researching on this matter right now, and later on will post the solution as an answer to my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop to add markers, add something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
           ... your code ...
        }
     })
)
```

In your code you need to determine the map size and put a translucent DIV over top, then show your own HTML absolutely-positioned DIV inside the map's weapping element.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the map style when clicked in the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
       map.set('styles', markerSelectedStyles);
    }
 })
```

)

You need to create your own version of a darker map.

[Maps Style Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

And create a style like this for instance:

```
var markerSelectedStyles = [ {
"stylers": [
  { "invert_lightness": true }
]}
]
```