# Google Maps marker event listener is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Here is a link to my test example and the code which I am trying to figure out.
http://www.gaiser-vfx.com/media/maptest.html

```
<div id="googleMap">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
<script>
    var noLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(52.1307, -3.78371);
    var initialLocation;
    var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
    var map;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        draggable: true,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 20,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    $('#LocationLatitude').val(center.lat().toFixed(5));$('#LocationLongitude').val(center.lng().toFixed(5));$('#LocationZoom').val(zoomLevel);});


    var poly
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#5555FF'
    });

    poly.setMap(map);
    poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);

    function addPoint(event) {
        path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    marker.setTitle("#" + path.length);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
        for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
            markers.splice(i, 1);
            path.removeAt(i);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
                path.setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

`

This is the example I am trying to follow.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html

One of the main differences between my code and the example is the use of an initialize function call in the example while I am just trying to load mine when it loads the page. On my map test, I am able to place markers on the map and pick them up and move them, but the function on each marker that updates the poly to the new marker point and the ability to delete each marker does not seem to work.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854431/how-to-when-marker-is-clicked-dim-the-map-and-show-a-big-div-instead-of-an-in/10854743#10854743

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you have to do is declare a `markers` variable visible to the event listeners:

```
...
var markers = [];
var poly;
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;
...
```